# Reading data from .txt file with multiple delimiter in R

Tags: r, delimiter

Can anyone tell me as how to read the data from .txt file which has multiple delimiter. Consider the below example for reference,

< Mike >////????[011]-[234564]///>>>[ABC]

< Hardley davidson >///??[080]-[42071186]..[DEC]

My Output should be as follows,

Mike 011234564 ABC

Hardley davidson 08042071186 DEC

Thanks & Regards, 
Mohan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could read it with `readLines` and then use regex to remove the unwanted characters

```
 gsub('(?<=[0-9])\\s+(?=[0-9])|^\\s+|\\s+$', '', 
       gsub('[[:punct:]]+', ' ', lines), perl=TRUE)
#[1] "Mike  011234564 ABC"               "Hardley davidson  08042071186 DEC"
```

Or we can use a single `sub` if the pattern is similar

```
sub(".*\\<([^> ]+)[^0-9]+([0-9]+)[^0-9]+([0-9]+)[^A-Z]+([A-Z]+).*", 
           "\\1 \\2\\3 \\4", lines)
#[1] "Mike 011234564 ABC"       "davidson 08042071186 DEC"
```

#### data

```
lines <- readLines(textConnection("< Mike >////????[011]-[234564]///>>>[ABC]
 < Hardley davidson >///??[080]-[42071186]..[DEC]"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. In case if i receive a .txt file which is around say 100 MB with similar kindly of data. In that case as well should we follow the same procedure as you have mentioned.... or is there a package or function in R to read the entire file such kind of data... like read.csv.. etc....

Comment: @MohanRaj  You can use `lines <- readLines('yourfile.txt')` and then do the change with `sub`.  But, there are other options with `awk/sed` if you are using a `linux` system without even reading the dataset